# Django - return each model value without field

Tags: python, django

The `Priority` model has three values, for each of them values I'm returning an `inlineform` which allows the user to set a score for each priority & then save with the Project.

This is what it currently looks like: [Current view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zkmbc.png)

My problem is: how can I automatically show all the priority values and allow the user to enter the score but not have to pick the `Priority`. Is it possible to show it like the image below?

[What I'm trying to do.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4rZw.png)

**Views.py**

```
class ProjectCreateview(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Project
    form_class = ProjectCreationForm
    login_url = "/login/"
    success_url = '/'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):

        PriorityChildFormset = inlineformset_factory(
            Project, ProjectPriority, fields=('project', 'priority', 'score'), can_delete=False, extra=Priority.objects.count(),
        )

        data = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.POST:
            data['priorities'] = PriorityChildFormset(self.request.POST)
        else:
            data['priorities'] = PriorityChildFormset()
        return data

    def form_valid(self, form):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        prioritycriteria = context["priorities"]
        form.instance.creator = self.request.user
        self.object = form.save()
        prioritycriteria.instance = self.object
        if prioritycriteria.is_valid():
            prioritycriteria.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

**Models.py**

```
class Priority(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(verbose_name="Priority Name", max_length=250)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
    
class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name="Name", max_length=100)
    details = models.TextField(verbose_name="Details/Description", blank=False)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
class ProjectPriority(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    priority = models.ForeignKey(Priority, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    score = models.CharField(max_length=1000, choices=priority_choices)
    
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Priority"
        verbose_name_plural = "Priorities"
```

**Template**

```html
<table class="table table-light">
  <tbody>
  {{ priorities.management_form }}
    {% for priority in priorities.forms %}
    <tr>
      {% for field in priority.visible_fields %}
      <td>
        {{ field.errors.as_ul }}
        {{ field }}
      </td>
      {% endfor %}
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using `initial` data with your formset (see the Django documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/formsets/#using-initial-data-with-a-formset)).

In your views.py code you can add this line to generate some `initial` values for the `priority` fields:

```py
initial = [{'priority': priority} for priority in Priority.objects.all()]
```

And then pass it to your formset:

```py
data['priorities'] = PriorityChildFormset(initial=initial)
```

Note that `initial` expects a list of the same length as the formset you created, which is defined by the `extra` parameter. This works because both of these parameters have been defined using the same base queryset (i.e. `Priority.objects`). If a filter were applied - it would need to apply in both places.

#### Changing how it displays

In addition, if you want to prevent the `priority` fields from being changed by the user using the dropdown menu, you can pass a `widgets` keyword argument to `inlineformset_factory` to set a `disabled` attribute on the `<select>` element that gets generated e.g.:

```py
from django import forms
...

widgets={'priority': forms.Select(attrs={'disabled': True})}
```

If you want the field to show *only* text - this is more difficult. The string representation of the related object that we want is buried in the field choices that are used to generate each `<option>`. If you want to do this, you can dig out each field manually:

```html
{% for priority in priorities.forms %}
  <tr>
    <td>
      {{ priority.priority.errors.as_ul }}
      {% for value, name in priority.priority.field.choices %}
        {% if value == priority.priority.value %}
          {{ name }}
        {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
      {{ priority.priority.as_hidden }}
    </td>
    <td>
      {{ priority.score.errors.as_ul }}
      {{ priority.score }}
    </td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you, works great. Anyway to style the field to look like text instead of a dropdown?

Comment: There's a few ways to skin that cat. I edited my answer to include a template-based solution. Other solutions might include using custom CSS to make it look like text and creating a custom widget.